# Which lightning-riding creature has a gliding speed and electric immunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, content-identification

I can't track down a creature I've read about: it has a gliding speed, immunity to electric damage, and when hit by electric damage could teleport to its source. This resulted in its habit of seeking high places during thunderstorms, so it could be hit by lightning, teleport into the clouds and enjoy the ride home.

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your creature is found in the Lords of Madness supplement, p. 171 and is called the zeugalak.

> > it has a gliding speed
>
> **Feather Fall (Su)**: At will, a zeugalak can use a feather fall
> effect (as the spell, caster level 16th) with personal range.

> > immunity to electric damage
>
> **Electrical Affinity (Su)**: A zeugalak takes no damage
> from electricity. [...]

> > and when hit by electric damage could teleport to its source
>
> **Electrical Teleportation (Su)**: If a zeugalak gains points to
> its Dexterity from an electricity-based attack, it can instantly
> teleport (as the spell greater teleport) to the source of the electrical
> attack.

> > This resulted in its habit of seeking high places during thunderstorms, so it could be hit by lightning, teleport into the clouds and enjoy the ride home.
>
> Zeugalaks are especially active during thunderstorms, and cavort atop mountain peaks during such weather. Their terrible bellows of delight when they are struck by bolts of lightning can carry for miles. When struck, they use their electrical teleportation ability to teleport high into the clouds above so they can enjoy the long feather fall back to the ground below through the surrounding storm.

Comment: When possible, you should edit in a quote or more detailed explanation to show how the creature you reference matches OP's description.

Comment: @V2Blast: Added for the OP; it's indeed an exact match with the description, I'm impressed by such a recollection feat!